# Displaying Pdf in Javafx using PDFJS library in Webview

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-8, pdf.js

My goal is to display pdf documents in my JavaFX application. After researching I came across Mozilla's PDFJS library and found it pretty useful. What I'm doing is reading PDF file as a byte array from JAVA and calling the js code in Web view. Here is the code.

**JAVA CODE**

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:\\test\\test.pdf"));
    String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);   


    btn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        String js = "openFileFromBase64('" + base64 + "')";
        engine.executeScript(js);
    });
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
var openFileFromBase64 = function(data) {
    var arr = base64ToArrayBuffer(data);
    PDFViewerApplication.open(arr);
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
  var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(len));
  alert(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}
```

**Problem**

I'm able to render some pdf files just fine but I've some pdf files that won't open correctly. So I did some analysis and found following:-

1. The problematic pdf files open correctly in adobe reader, firefox and edge browser.
2. I thought the problem might be PDFJS library. So I tried placing my pdf file in  WEB directory and opened viewer.html. To my surprise
   the pdf displayed correctly.
3. I thought maybe some bytes are lost when I send data from Java to Javascript.So I printed number of bytes on each end and they match.
4. Finally, I thought that java might be messing up the encoding. So I read the file from java and wrote the bytes to separate file and the file generated is correct.

I'm trying to understand if I overlooked something. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is how my pdf looks like after it is rendered:-
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF doesn't load at all in javafx webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666551/pdf-doesnt-load-at-all-in-javafx-webview)

Comment: No sure why this was marked duplicate of the mentioned link. The   User is trying to load the pdf via url whereas I’m passing the byte array which is base64 encoded. The bug they are talking about, which is fixed in java 9 has nothing to do with the problem I mentioned. Please, read the full description and the code given before you mark them duplicate as it wastes time of other people.

Comment: What version of java are you using?  Looking at you attached Image, one could assume it's a problem related to fonts.

Comment: You need to stop assuming and read the bug on java site and my question. Java website clearly states the webview is never populated which is exactly what the user has reported in the link you posted. Here is the link to bug on java website: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180825

Also, if you will read what I have written above then you will understand that I'm able to load some pdf file correctly.

Comment: Nothing is in stone. Did you miss the part where it says "Possible duplicate"? With the emphasis on "Possible". No one time is being wasted. Each individual can come and have a look and move forward based on what they get from the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem: **No text would render properly** in the JavaFX WebView using the current stable release of PDF.js as of today (**v2.0.943**). Image based PDFs render properly.

Having a look at the PDF.js release notes, I found that [v2.0.943](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/tag/v2.0.943) introduced lots of changes related to fonts and seem to have broken the font rendering in JavaFX.

The good news is that **the current pre-release**, [v2.1.266](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/tag/v2.1.266) has [some bugfixes](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/10539) regarding the handling of fonts and it **fixes the text rendering problem** in the JavaFX WebView.

If you don't feel confortable using a pre-release, you can use [v1.10.100](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/tag/v1.10.100), text rendering works with this version too, although I recommend using the latest version, because it seems to render the different fonts much better.

Comment: Thank You Oizulain. This worked like a charm.  I tried version 2.1.266.